# What or who is test author?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

While learning testing with Espresso in Android I came across this term where the documentation for [ViewInteraction](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/support/test/espresso/ViewInteraction.html) states that this class

> Provides the primary interface for test authors to perform actions or
>   asserts on views.

Also while learning naming conventions for unit testing in an [article](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) the writer states that

> You do not need to name them with a CONST casing , but the name does
>   have to represent the intent of the test author.

So what or who is the test author, is it the person who writes tests or some class or unit that is used as a test author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test author is the person (developer) who writes the code for the test.